# A required class was missing while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, maven, kotlin, intellij-idea

I am trying to run a spring-boot Kotlin project.

When running `mvn clean install` I am getting this error:

```
A required class was missing while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.4.10:compile: org/jetbrains/kotlin/cli/common/messages/MessageCollector
```

Good to mention that I do not have a folder named `cli` under `.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/`

I tried to delete the `repository` folder and build again but that didn’t help.

I am using maven 3.6.3, JDK 11 and Kotlin compiler 1.4 which match with the config of the project.

If someone could help, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The Kotlin compiler jar was broken for some reason. Downloading it from here and replacing it fixed the problem, in case somebody faces the same problem in the future! :)